# RunLWC Function from Aura Parent Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I'm trying to run a method in my child component (**LWC component**) from my parent component (**Aura Component**) but the method is never run.

**Parent** (Aura Helper)

```
    const months = component.find("month");
    for(let i=0; i < months.length; i++){
        months[i].getAllDays();   
    }
```

**Child** (Aura)

```
    @api
    getAllDays(){
        console.log('Check');
    }
```

The components "month" are found. I can get attributes if I do:

```
months[i].get("v.myVar");
```

I can't run exposed functions.
Have you any ideas ?

**EDIT**

The problem is that my parent component initialization is faster than my child component loading and it can't run the function. My syntax is good

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Can you provide some more code of your problem, like HTML files of your components?

Comment: Removed my answer, as it wasn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that my parent component initialization is faster than my child component loading and it can't run the function. My syntax is good